# CF7 hook breaks form after submit

Tags: wordpress, code-snippets, contact-form-7

I'm trying to use some CF7 hooks, but they seem to break something in the workflow after the submit.

I tried for example to add the following snippet to print something in the console:

```
function debug_to_console($cf7) {
    echo '<div display="none"><script type="text/javascript">console.log("console log message");</script></div>';
    //return $cf7;
}

add_action( 'wpcf7_before_send_mail', 'debug_to_console' );
```

When I enable it, nothing gets printed in the console and the [response](the notification after submitting the form) stops working.
The email instead gets delivered.
Any idea?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use javascript events for frontend. https://contactform7.com/dom-events/

If you want fire action before ajax call use:

```
$('.wpcf7-form').submit(function() {
    // action
});
```

Comment: Hi Patryk, thank you for the answer! My aim though is not to show stuff in the frontend. I just used the echo as a "console.log()" to have a feedback for myself, but the final aim is to perform some automatic operations, that's why I'm using `add_action( 'wpcf7_before_send_mail', 'debug_to_console' );`

Answer (score 0):

We can not echo the result to front end from the wordpress hooks.

Try [DOM Events from Contact form 7](https://contactform7.com/dom-events/)

```
document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7submit', function( event ) {
        var entry = event.detail.inputs.find(element => element.name == 'entry_id');
        switch(event.detail.contactFormId){
            case "220": case "222": 
               alert(event.detail);
            break;

            default : console.log("Error");break;
        }
```